# Node.js: How to avoid 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' error when using Sequelize and Telegraf?

Tags: javascript, import, sequelize.js, require, telegraf

Use import and require at same time

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

import {Telegraf} from 'telegraf'

const bot = new Telegraf("Token")



const sequelize = new Sequelize("bot", "admin", {
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "disk:/path/to/database"
});
```

I want to use Sequalize and Telegraf libs. But when I node the file (index.js) I get error:

```
import {Telegraf} from 'telegraf'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Then I add to my package.json "type":"module" and get this error:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
                  ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

So I tried to node index.js, node index.cjs, .mjs and I tried to separate bot and database but it's didn't work.

How I can fix it?

Comment: Your code is trying to mix CommonJS modules (`require()`) with native modules (`import`). You can use one or the other, not both (in a given module).

Comment: have you tried `import Sequelize from "sequelize";` ? (In the ES module version of the code)

Comment: Yes, I tried. Error:  throw new Error("Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0");
            ^
Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Comment: That's an error from Sequelize I think, so you've gotten over the import issues.  The "dialect" is how you tell Sequelize what kind of database you're connecting to.